# Feature Request: Auto-Star Option

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, profile-page

A feature I think should be added to the SO settings page is the option to automatically favorite/star questions that YOU create, answer, comment on, or any combination thereof.

For example, Bill, the average SO user, might want to favorite all questions he asks.

Bob, a more active user, might want to favorite all questions he answers.

Joe, a SO guru, may want to favorite every question he asks, answers, and comments on.

If you *really* want to implement this to its fullest, you could make an option to also favorite any question you edit or vote to mark/close, etc. or even an option to favorite any question you flag!

Comment: "_Joe, a SO guru, may want to favorite every question he asks, answers, and comments on._" this one in particular I think would make all favorites meaningless.  You can already see your ask/answer/comment/edit/close history in your profile.  And you are notified about activity on questions you ask, so there's not too much reason to favorite them as well.

Comment: Don't you already get notified when a question you asked gets a new answer or comment? What would favoriting your own question add?

Comment: Imagine _how many favorites_ will you end up with! Favorites are, well, _favorites_, questions you _found useful_ and may want to return to later.

Comment: I'd love to see a granular favorites embeded on the system but suspect it's not really on high priority... But, we are programmers and the API is there, all our (and others') favorites and their tags are easily available. Building an external interface is pretty straightforward... Making it good and available to everyone, well, that'd be golden :)

Answer (score 15):

What would be the point in starring/favoriting questions that you have asked or answered? Such questions are already listed in your profile, under the "questions" and "answers" tabs, respectively. There doesn't seem to be any benefit in duplicating those lists under the "favorites" tab as well.

You can also get a list of all your comments in your profile, too. Click on the "all actions" tab, and then filter by "comments." If you're a true SO guru like Joe, you'll have zillions of these. Very unlikely that you would want all of these questions to be favorited.

A list of favorites is most useful when it contains hand-picked questions that you find particularly interesting or relevant, and want to save so that you can find them easily. It doesn't make sense to favorite everything, because it will become too difficult to pick out the signal from the noise.

Comment: To be fair, favoriting a question you answer could be potentially useful if you are interesting in seeing other answers to the same question.  But yeah, there would be too much noise for it auto-favoriting to be useful.